# puma initializer does not work with rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, puma

I have installed puma many times before and have never had this problem.  I am following heroku's instructions verbatim.  I have created a `Procfile` with this inside:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Here is the configuration file puma.rb:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

When I start the server by running `rails s` or `rails s puma` i get

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/david/projects/abc/config/initializers/puma.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `workers' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

What is happening and how do I fix it?  I am using sqlite3 in development and postgresql in production but i get the same error in both environments.  I am using rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `gem 'puma'` in your Gemfile

Edit: The puma.rb should not be located in the initializers folder, but outside in the config folder. Thanks Nicolai

Comment: I do.  I have the gem and I've bundled it.

Comment: Could you try adding ``require 'puma'`` before ``workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)`` line?

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that.  I still get the same error though.

Comment: I have copy/pasted your config into my existing Rails 4.2 app and it is working fine (our configs are the same). I have ``puma (2.12.3)`` and ``rails (4.2.1)``

Comment: I know.  It should work.  I have at least 15 other rails apps with the EXACT same configuration, so I don't know why this is not working.

Comment: Oh, Im using puma 2.11.0.  How do I make it use the latest version?

Comment: Must be related to your gem list. Do you have ``rvm`` or something like that?

Comment: Hmm, tried 2.12.3 and its still not working.  I am using rvm

Comment: I bundle updated Puma and its now using 2.13.4 and still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88134/discussion-between-zepplock-and-philip7899).

Comment: Zepplock, you answered my question in the chat a while ago.  If you post it here, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The `puma.rb` should not be located in the initializers folder, but outside in the config folder